# How to overcome out of memory exception with PrintWriter?

Tags: java, csv, printwriter

The following code reads a bunch of .csv files and then combines them into one .csv file. I tried to `system.out.println` ... all datapoints are correct, however when i try to use the `PrintWriter` I get:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

I tried to use `FileWriter` but got the same error. How should I correct my code?

```
public class CombineCsv {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter output  = new PrintWriter("C:\\User\\result.csv");
        final File file = new File("C:\\Users\\is");
        int i = 0;
        for (final File child: file.listFiles()) {
            BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "C:\\Users\\is\\"+child.getName()));
            String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); 
            while (dataRow != null) {
                String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
                for (String item:dataArray) { 
                    System.out.println(item + "\t");
                    output.append(item+","+child.getName().replaceAll(".csv", "")+",");
                    i++;
                }
                dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
            } // Close the file once all data has been read.
            CSVFile.close();
        } 
        output.close();
        System.out.println(i);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of two scenarios in which that code could result in an OOME:

- If the `file` directory has a very large number of elements, then `file.listFiles()` could create a very large array of `File` objects.
- If one of the input files includes a line that is very long, then `CSVFile.readLine()` could use a lot of memory in the process of reading it.  (Up to 6 times the number of bytes in the line.)

The simplest approach to solving both of these issues is to increase the Java heap size using the `-Xmx` JVM option.

---

I can see no reason why your use of a `PrintWriter` would be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The number of files is 18. Each file contains 30,000 records (around 500 Kb)

Comment: 18 files shouldn't cause a problem.  The number of records isn't the issue either.  My theory is that issue is that one of the files you are reading contains a very long line.  Try to figure out which file is being read when the OOME occurs, and then narrow it down to a line within that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`boolean autoFlush = true;
 PrintWriter output  = new PrintWriter(myFileName, autoFlush);`

It creates a PrintWriter instance which flushes content everytime when there is a new line or format.